# JAVA money change

Tags: java, if-statement, output

I am trying to write a code that output the money change something like this :

```
**$7.00 remains to be paid. Enter coin or note: $100.00

  You gave $100.00

Your change:

1 x $50.00

2 x $20.00

0 x $10.00

0 x $5.00

1 x $2.00

1 x $1.00

  **
```

but the output should be the same but without showing the 0 values, for example it should be like this :

```
**$7.00 remains to be paid. Enter coin or note: $100.00

  You gave $100.00

Your change:

1 x $50.00

2 x $20.00

1 x $2.00

1 x $1.00
  **
```

my money change code looks something like this, using if statements:

```
  double fiftyDollars, twentyDollars, tenDollars, fiveDollars, twoDollars, oneDollar, fiftyCents, twentyCents, tenCents, fiveCents;

        fiftyDollars = change / 50.00; //dividing change by
        change = change % 50.00; //get remainder of the change
                if(fiftyDollars > 0) {
                    System.out.println((int) fiftyDollars + " x $50.00"); //getting output as integer- casting
                }

                twentyDollars = change / 20.00;
        change = change % 20.00;
                if (twentyDollars > 0){
                    System.out.println((int) twentyDollars + " x $20.00");
                }

        tenDollars = change / 10.00;
        change = change % 10.00;
                if (tenDollars >0) {
                    System.out.println((int) tenDollars + " x $10.00");
                }

        fiveDollars = change / 5.00;
        change = change % 5.00;
                if(fiveDollars > 0) {
                    System.out.println((int) fiveDollars + " x $5.00");
                }

        twoDollars = change / 2.00;
        change = change % 2.00;
                if (twoDollars >0) {
                    System.out.println((int) twoDollars + " x $2.00");
                }

        oneDollar = change / 1.00;
        change = change % 1.00;
                if(oneDollar >0) {
                    System.out.println((int) oneDollar + " x $1.00");
                }

        fiftyCents = change / 0.5;
        change = change % 0.5;
                if (fiftyCents >0) {
                    System.out.println((int) fiftyCents + " x $0.50");
                }

        twentyCents = change / 0.2;
        change = change % 0.2;
                if(twentyCents > 0) {
                    System.out.println((int) twentyCents + " x $0.20");
                }

        tenCents = change / 0.1;
        change = change % 0.1;
                if (tenCents > 0){
                    System.out.println((int) tenCents + " x $0.10");
                }

        fiveCents = change / 0.05;
        change = change % 0.05;
                if (fiveCents > 0){
                    System.out.println((int) fiveCents + " x $0.05");
                }
```

I would appreciate any help from you guys ! 
THANK YOU

Comment: Consider providing a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Replace `double` by `int` calculating with cents.

Comment: When you convert `double` to an `int` or better a `long` I suggest you round the result with `long cents = (long) Math.round(x * 100)` rather than truncate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using doubles, so the 0 values are be between zero and 1,
if you cast the double to ints in the if clause your programm should work fine.

Comment: If you cast a double to int the number 0.9999999 will get the int value 0 which is not what you would expect. Better to compare with double a safety margin:
if(tenDollars > 0.01d)

Comment: if your chage is 25$ and you check `if(fiftyDollars > 0.01d)`it will return true, because 50/25 = 0.5, but you wont get 50$ change back

Comment: True, so it should be:
if(fiftyDollars >= 1.0d)

Comment: This is exactly the same I did, 0.9999999 will be still less than 1.0d, there are many tutorials that explain how to compare doubles correctly because of errors due to rounding in floating point arithmetics.

Answer (score 2):

You may check for values equal or superior to 1.

As said in the other answer, you are dealing with `double` values, so `>0` will match `0.1` , `0.56`, etc ..

So :

```
if (tenDollars >= 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change all your if conditions like this

```
if(fiftyDollars > 0) {
```

To

```
if((int)fiftyDollars > 0) {
```